# Filter by month in django view

Tags: python, django

I am very new in in Django and Python and this is going to be a very basic question.

I am facing problem while i am trying to add a **Full Text Search** mechanism in my django powered app.

***Explanation Of The Search Mechanism*:**
                                                                                            I have an **UserCommission** model,where commission data is storing against different types of user and obviously my UserCommission model have created_time field,which is a **DateTimeField**.Now i am trying to search users commission against each month.

this is my view file(only the form)

```
   <form role="form" method='post' action='/showphoto/user_commission_results/'>
         <tr>
              {% csrf_token %}

                 <td><select name="year">
                    <option value="January">January</option>
                    <option value="February">February</option>
                    <option value="March">March</option>
                    <option value="April">April</option>
                    <option value="May">May</option>
                    <option value="June">June</option>
                    <option value="July">July</option>
                    <option value="August">August</option>
                    <option value="September">September</option>
                    <option value="October">October</option>
                    <option value="November">November</option>
                    <option value="December">December</option>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <input type='submit' value='search' />
            </td>
         </tr>
    </form>
```

This is my model

```
class UserCommission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField('Created Time',auto_now_add=True)
    commission = models.IntegerField()
```

and this is my view for search

```
def user_commission_results(request):
    year = request.POST.get('year')
    commission_results = UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time.month=year)

    return render_to_response('photo/user_commission_results.html',{'commission_results':commission_results},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but i am facing the following error,

```
 SyntaxError at /
 keyword can't be an expression (views.py, line 154)
```

this line 154 is indicating the **

```
commission_results = UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time.month=year)
```

of my view file.

since i am almost a novice,i can't figure out whats wrong is going on.
Is it a right way to make a **Full Text Seacrh** in django? if it is ,then what wrong i have done here?

**UPDATE**:
The wrong i was doing that i have used dot(.) in the Filter parameter in my view

```
commission_results = UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time.month=year)
```

which actually causing the error,now changed it like this

```
commission_results = UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time__month=year)
```

but now i am a error which is

```
 ValueError at /showphoto/user_commission_results/
 invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'May'
```

after selecting a month(May) to search.

Comment: whats `""` after `else` in your view ? you got a  `SyntaxError` error !

Comment: is it causing the error? @Kasra

Comment: no i just ask ! i think the error is because of `.` inside ` UserCommission.objects.filter`  would you pls say whats the line `154` in your view ?

Comment: Your argument `created_time.month=year` is causing the problem. You can try `UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time__year=year)` to filter based on `created_time.year`

Comment: but this is a month based search @maackle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use dot in arguments names so this part `UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time.month=year)` causes `SyntaxError`
 so you must change it to `UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time__month=year)`

for more info read **[exac](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-exact)** in Django site !

**Django site says** :

> In MySQL, a database table’s “collation” setting determines whether exact comparisons are case-sensitive. This is a database setting, not a Django setting. It’s possible to configure your MySQL tables to use case-sensitive comparisons, but some trade-offs are involved. For m
>   ore information about this, see the [collation section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#mysql-collation) in the [databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/) documentation.

and for last error you can change the value of your inputs in your template:

```
                <option value="1">January</option>
                <option value="2">February</option>
                <option value="3">March</option>
                <option value="4">April</option>
                <option value="5">May</option>
                <option value="6">June</option>
                <option value="7">July</option>
                <option value="8">August</option>
                <option value="9">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
```

Comment: will it be a double underscore or a single underscore, that is created_time__month or created_time_month?

Comment: must be double underscore !

Comment: i have edited my code according to your answer, and then trying to search selecting the month **September**, but now i am facing this error **ValueError at /showphoto/user_commission_results/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'September'**

Comment: its because of your value (`september`) your month field must be filled with a string number of month like '4' or '11' .

Comment: can you suggest me how can i do this?I am facing problem with django since i am very new.

Comment: `commission_results = UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time__month='11')`

Comment: i can't do it,cause i am passing it dynamically.

Comment: you need to change your values in template !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the month that's stored and retrieved by django is the month *number* not the month *name*.  There are many reasons for this, but one of the basic ones is that you may be developing a site for multiple languages, so its a lot easier to store the number and then display January, janvier or Januar or enero depending on what language the user speaks.

The easiest way to fix this is to change the template so that the value is the month number:

```
<select name="year">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

You might also want to consider that the name is `year` but you are actually sending the month, and rename it accordingly.